# systemd user service does not start at boot

Tags: systemd

Seems my user service didn't run at all after reboot and user login.

```
$ cat ~/.config/systemd/user/ibus.service
[Unit]
Description=Intelligent Input Bus
Documentation=man:ibus-daemon(1)
Conflicts=fcitx.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ibus-daemon --replace --xim
ExecReload=/usr/bin/ibus restart
ExecStop=/usr/bin/ibus exit
Environment=GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus XMODIFIERS="@im=ibus" QT_IM_MODULE=ibus

[Install]
Alias=input-method.service
```

```
$ systemctl --user is-enabled ibus.service
enabled                      
$ systemctl --user is-active ibus.service
inactive
```

There is no log from journalctl `journalctl --user-unit=ibus.service`, I've tried `reenable` but still didn't work.